# Font GM Londinium

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I need to use the font "GM Londinium" in a certificate header. But I can't find the downloadable font. Could anyone suggest some alternate fonts similar to GM Londinium or else suggestions as to where it can be downloaded from.

I used [Myfonts](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) to check the font name. I am providing the fonts that I need(I can't post more than two links, hence I have altered the links as here).

[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/38845385/title.png]

[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/38845385/tcert.png]

I'm using an SVG file.

Comment: What indication is there that the original header font was [GM Londinium](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/munchfonts/londinium/)? The sample you provided is certainly not using that font, a few of the glyphs are noticeably different

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first image is a Gothic/Medieval type font. There are many like it, even free ones. Check them out [here](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=401&text=Computer). Both [Old London](http://www.dafont.com/old-london.font?text=Computer) and [Cloister Black](http://www.dafont.com/cloister-black.font?text=Computer) appear indistinguishable from the sample you provided.

[image: Old London]

The second font looks like [Chopin Script](http://www.dafont.com/chopin-script.font?text=Certificate).

[image: Chopin Script]